# Magento 2 - State/Province dropdown and Country Dropdown in Contact form

Tags: magento2, forms, contact-form, country-regions, state

I need to add these 2 dropdowns to the contact form.  How would I pull in those values for each dropdown?

Comment: You want to transfer `State/Province dropdown and Country Dropdown` from Checkout page to Contact form?

Comment: Yes, I would like those as being required on the contact page.

Answer (score 14):

Following method will add Country and Region dropdown to contact us form,

[namespace]/[modulename]/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Contact\Block\ContactForm" type="[namespace]\[modulename]\Block\ContactForm" />
</config>
```

[namespace]/[modulename]/Block/ContactForm

```
<?php

namespace [namespace]\[modulename]\Block;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class ContactForm extends \Magento\Contact\Block\ContactForm
{

    public function __construct(
            Template\Context $context,
            \Magento\Directory\Block\Data $directoryBlock, 
            array $data = []
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->_isScopePrivate = true;
        $this->directoryBlock = $directoryBlock;
    }

    public function getCountries()
    {
        $country = $this->directoryBlock->getCountryHtmlSelect();
        return $country;
    }
    public function getRegion()
    {
        $region = $this->directoryBlock->getRegionHtmlSelect();
        return $region;
    }
}
```

[namespace]/[modulename]/view/frontend/templates/form.phtml

```
<?php
$countryList=$block->getCountries();
$regionList=$block->getRegion();
?>
<div class="field country">
    <label class="label" for="country"><span><?php echo __('Country') ?></span></label>
    <div class="control">
        <?php echo $countryList?>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="field country">
    <label class="label" for="region"><span><?php  echo __('Region') ?></span></label>
    <div class="control">
        <?php echo $regionList?>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Additional**

So here is the further information for you to fetch region based on selected country

In you JS

```
$(document).on('change','#country',function() {
    var param = 'country='+$('#country').val();
    $.ajax({
        showLoader: true,
        url: YOUR_URL_HERE,
        data: param,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: 'json'
    }).done(function (data) {
        //data.value has the array of regions
    });
});
```

In your controller

```
public function __construct(
        Context       $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory    $resultJsonFactory,
        \Magento\Directory\Model\RegionFactory $regionColFactory,
        PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {        
        $this->regionColFactory     = $regionColFactory;
        $this->resultJsonFactory            = $resultJsonFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $this->_view->loadLayout();
        $this->_view->getLayout()->initMessages();
        $this->_view->renderLayout();

        $result                 = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();
        $regions=$this->regionColFactory->create()->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('country_id',$this->getRequest()->getParam('country'));
        return $result->setData(['success' => true,'value'=>$regions->getData()]);

    }
```

If you need any further help for ajax and data to be presented in phtml file please refer to [this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/128669/how-to-make-a-simple-ajax-call-in-magento-2-1-0/128670#128670)

Comment: How can we make the region value dependent based on country.

Comment: fire ajax command and pass selected value of country dropdown as parameter then fetch records from directory_country_region according to selected country

Comment: there are some predefined function in Magento/Directory/Model/Region.php you can use those to fetch region by country code, even have a look at  Magento/Directory/Model/ResourceModel/Region.php

Comment: @krishnaijjada I have updated answer which further informs how to have ajax call to fetch region based on selected country. Hope that helps

Comment: Clear answer + 1, Out of curiosity in customer address edit file we can find script at the end. Doe't it help full ? ..:)
vendor\magento\module-customer\view\frontend\templates\address\edit.phtml

Comment: @krishnaijjada you can try that method as well, I have not tried it yet.

Comment: Use getRegionSelect. The method getRegionHtmlSelect() is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

```
    In Phtml
    <div class="field company required">
                <label class="label" for="company"><span><?php echo __('Company') ?></span></label>
                <div class="control">
                    <input name="company" id="company" title="<?php echo __('company') ?>" value="" class="input-text letters-only" type="text" data-validate="{required:true,'letters-only':true}" style="width:400px"/>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="field country required">
                <label class="label" for="country"><span><?php echo __('Country') ?></span></label>
                <div class="control">
                   <?php echo $countryList?>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="field region required">
                <label class="label" for="region"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('State/Province') ?></span></label>
                <div class="control">
                    <?php echo $regionList?>
                </div>
            </div>
<script>
    require(["jquery"], function ($) {
$(document).on('change','#country',function() {
            //alert($('#country').val());
            if(document.getElementById('states')){
                document.getElementById('states').value = '';
            }
            if(document.getElementById('state')){
                document.getElementById('state').value = '';
            }
             var param = 'country='+$('#country').val();
             $.ajax({
                     showLoader: true,
                     url: '<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getCatalogrequest(); ?>',
                     data: param,
                     type: "GET",
                     dataType: 'json'
             }).done(function (data) {

                 if(data.value=='')
                 {
                     $('.field.states.required').show();
                     $('.field.region.required').hide();
                 }
                 else
                 {
                    $('.field.states.required').hide();
                    $('.field.region.required').show();
                    $('#state').empty().append(data.value);
                 }
            });
    });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need AJAX for that. Just look at the customer add/edit address form.

template: `vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/address/edit.phtml`

block: `vendor/magento/module-customer/Block/Address/Edit.php`

Keep the only fields and methods you need in your custom template and block class.