# Add state/province to product page in magento 2

Tags: magento2, product-page

I'm new in magento 2. How can I add state/province to product page? I did [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/128825/magento-2-state-province-dropdown-and-country-dropdown-in-contact-form/128847#) instructions, it works on contact page but on product page this error appears:
[image: error msg]

My block is:

```
    <?php
namespace Ilho\Region\Block;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Magento\Framework\ObjectManager;
class ProductView extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Url\EncoderInterface $urlEncoder,
        \Magento\Framework\Json\EncoderInterface $jsonEncoder,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\StringUtils $string,
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product $productHelper,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductTypes\ConfigInterface $productTypeConfig,
        \Magento\Framework\Locale\FormatInterface $localeFormat,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
        \Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface $priceCurrency,
        \Magento\Directory\Block\Data $directoryBlock, 
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_productHelper = $productHelper;
        $this->urlEncoder = $urlEncoder;
        $this->_jsonEncoder = $jsonEncoder;
        $this->productTypeConfig = $productTypeConfig;
        $this->string = $string;
        $this->_localeFormat = $localeFormat;
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->priceCurrency = $priceCurrency;
        $this->directoryBlock = $directoryBlock;
        parent::__construct(
            $context,
            $data
        );
    }

    public function getCountries()
    {
        $country = $this->directoryBlock->getCountryHtmlSelect();
        return $country;
    }
    public function getRegion()
    {
        $region = $this->directoryBlock->getRegionHtmlSelect();
        return $region;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we are talking about block file in magento it is must to call

```
\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
```

In the constructor section you have called the context of **Catalog block**. Do replace in your code

```
\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
```

with

```
\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
```

Then run the below command from your magento root to see the change

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

> Note: Try to avoid the use of Object_manager into your code it is not
>   considered in to the best practice of magento try to create inject its
>   dependencies via block files or any other functions in to the block
>   file only.

Thank you!