# magento 2 How to make city drop down in checkout page

Tags: magento2, checkout

I Want To city drop down like country and state option in checkout page.

Comment: This should help/guide you https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/128825/magento-2-state-province-dropdown-and-country-dropdown-in-contact-form

Comment: Thank for comment but  I Want to city drop down like country field in checkout page.

Comment: refer this one https://github.com/EaDesgin/Magento2-City-Dropdown and this one https://packagist.org/packages/php-cuong/magento2-city-dropdown also refer this maybe it will help you https://github.com/vincent2090311/magento2-address

Comment: @VishalBaraiya: Have you find any solution for this issue?, If yes please share or guide me