# Magento 2: How to send data using Ajax form in custom form?

Tags: magento2, ajax

Can anyone explain me how I can create a simple form on Magento-2 page to send data using Ajax? 
I already have a form and controller action, that send data without using ajax.

Comment: I think this link will help you [click here](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/128669/how-to-make-a-simple-ajax-call-in-magento-2-1-0)

Comment: look at my answer, it could help more then the accepted one

Comment: Showing error to response > Undefined property:
> namespace\modulename\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor::$_jsonHelper Please share to improve the answer

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can just set below code in your phtml file to use ajax,
You have to change your **customurl** in below code,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(["jquery"],function($) {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var customurl = "<?php echo $this->getUrl().'frontname/index/index'?>";
            $.ajax({
                url: customurl,
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    customdata1: 'test1',
                    customdata2: 'test2',
                },
            complete: function(response) {             
                country = response.responseJSON.default_country;
                state = response.responseJSON.state;         
                console.log(state+' '+country);   
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, errorThrown) {
                    console.log('Error happens. Try again.');
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

inside your controller file **execute()** method,

```
<?php
 use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
 public function execute()
    {
        $resultPage = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_PAGE);

        $response = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_RAW);
        $response->setHeader('Content-type', 'text/plain');
        $country = 'india';
        $state = 'gujarat';
        $response->setContents(
            $this->_jsonHelper->jsonEncode(
                [
                    'default_country' => $country,
                    'state' => $state,
                ]
            )
        );
        return $response;
    }
```

Comment: but how i need to procces getted data in controller and give response? 
Now i just redirect user on static page with results after submiting form, but i need to show the result by ajax without redirecting.

Comment: you can get data in controller using $this->getRequest()->getParam('customdata1');

Comment: and what about response?

Comment: response is getting in script response.

Comment: complete: function(response)  here you have got response.

Comment: I talk about response from contoller. I need to return message after processing sended data.

Comment: you have to set response in above $this->_jsonHelper->jsonEncode(
                [
                    'default_country' => $country,
                    'state' => $state,
                ]
            ) code in controller

Comment: in above case default_country and state are return from response

Comment: How to display success message like in default magento 2 after success?

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya, can we create custom js file into theme, and include all js related code into it, instead of directly writing into phtml file

Answer (score 20):

Accepted answer is good, but i think could be useful take advantage of the js validation that magento core offers.
So, try to use below js script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
require([
    "jquery",
    "mage/mage"
],function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#form_id').mage(
            'validation',
            { 
                submitHandler: function(form) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "url to module/controller/action",
                        data: $('#form_id').serialize(),
                        type: 'POST',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        beforeSend: function() {
                            // show some loading icon
                        },
                        success: function(data, status, xhr) {
                            // data contains your controller response
                        },
                        error: function (xhr, status, errorThrown) {
                            console.log('Error happens. Try again.');
                            console.log(errorThrown);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        );
    });
});
</script>
```

Don't forget that controller has to return JSON response like:

```
$response = $this->resultFactory
    ->create(\Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON)
    ->setData([
        'status'  => "ok",
        'message' => "form submitted correctly"
    ]);

return $response;
```

Comment: Way better solution than the accepted answer. Thanks man

Answer (score 0):

Using `PrototypeJS`

```
<?php
/**
 * @var $block \Company\Module\Block\System\Config\Form\GenerateData
 */
?>
<script>
    require([
        'jquery',
        'prototype',
    ], function ($) {
        function generateData() {
            let params = {};
            new Ajax.Request('<?php echo $block->getAjaxUrl() ?>', {
                parameters: params,
                loaderArea: true,
                asynchronous: true,
                onSuccess: function (transport) {
                    let response = JSON.parse(transport.responseText);
                    $('#messages .message-success span.message-text').text("<?= __('Data generated successfully!') ?>");
                    $('#messages .message-success').show();
                    $('#messages .message-success').delay(8000).fadeOut();
                },
                onFailure: function() {
                    $('#messages .message-error span.message-text').text("<?= __('Something went wrong while generating the data.') ?>");
                    $('#messages .message-error').show();
                    $('#messages .message-error').delay(8000).fadeOut();
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }
        $('#generate_data').click(function () {
            generateData();
        });
    });
</script>

<div class="pp-buttons-container">
    <button id="<?= $block->getId() ?>">
        <span><span><span><?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getButtonLabel()) ?></span></span></span>
    </button>
</div>
<div id="messages" >
    <div class="messages">
        <div class="message message-success success" style="display: none;">
            <div data-ui-id="messages-message-success">
                <span class="message-text"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="message message-error error" style="display: none;">
            <div data-ui-id="messages-message-error">
                <span class="message-text"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```