# Product Review form in magento 2

Tags: frontend, controllers, ajax, magento2.2, product-review

I have modified product review form as popup modal, Now I have passed the form data through Ajax to my overrides controller, but it shows the below error.

> {"0":"Source class \"\XXX\YYY\Controller\Index\Result\" for
>   \"XXX\YYY\Controller\Index\ResultFactory\" generation does not
>   exist.","1":"

Please provide me a solution

[image]

**js file**

```
define(['jquery', 'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'], function (jQuery, modal) {
    return function (config) {

        var customFunction = {
            ajaxSubmit: function () {
                var form_data = jQuery("#review-form").serialize();
                alert(form_data);
                var reviewurl = config.url;
                alert(reviewurl);
                jQuery.ajax({
                    url: reviewurl,
                    type: 'POST',

                    data: form_data,
                    success: function (response) {
                        alert("successful");
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                        alert("failed");
                    }
                });
            },

            options: {
                type: 'popup',
                responsive: true,
                innerScroll: true,
                title: jQuery.mage.__('Product Review'),
                buttons: [{
                        text: jQuery.mage.__('submit'),
                        class: '',
                        click: function () {
                            //Ajax function call

                            customFunction.ajaxSubmit();
                            var close = this;
                            setTimeout(function () {
                                close.closeModal();

                            }, 3000);
                        }
                    }]
            }
        };
        jQuery(".product-reviews-summary").on('click', function () {

            modal(customFunction.options, jQuery('#popup-modal'));
            jQuery("#popup-modal").modal("openModal");

        });
        jQuery(".add-review").on('click', function () {

            modal(customFunction.options, jQuery('#popup-modal'));
            jQuery("#popup-modal").modal("openModal");

        });
        jQuery(".star-popup").on('click', function () {

            modal(customFunction.options, jQuery('#popup-modal'));
            jQuery("#popup-modal").modal("openModal");

        });
    };
});
```

**Controller**

```
namespace XXX\YYY\Controller\Index;

class Index extends \Magento\Review\Controller\Product\Post
{
    public function execute()
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);

        if (!$this->formKeyValidator->validate($this->getRequest())) {
            $resultRedirect->setUrl($this->_redirect->getRefererUrl());
            return $resultRedirect;
        }


        $data = $this->reviewSession->getFormData(true);
        print_r($data);

        if ($data) {
            $rating = [];

            if (isset($data['ratings']) && is_array($data['ratings'])) {
                $rating = $data['ratings'];
            }

        } else {
            $data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
            $rating = $this->getRequest()->getParam('ratings', []);
        }
        if (($product = $this->initProduct()) && !empty($data)) {
            /** @var \Magento\Review\Model\Review $review */
            $review = $this->reviewFactory->create()->setData($data);
            $review->unsetData('review_id');

            $validate = $review->validate();
            if ($validate === true) {
                try {
                    $review->setEntityId($review->getEntityIdByCode(Review::ENTITY_PRODUCT_CODE))
                            ->setEntityPkValue($product->getId())
                            ->setStatusId(Review::STATUS_PENDING)
                            ->setCustomerId($this->customerSession->getCustomerId())
                            ->setStoreId($this->storeManager->getStore()->getId())
                            ->setStores([$this->storeManager->getStore()->getId()])
                            ->save();

                    foreach ($rating as $ratingId => $optionId) {
                        $this->ratingFactory->create()
                                ->setRatingId($ratingId)
                                ->setReviewId($review->getId())
                                ->setCustomerId($this->customerSession->getCustomerId())
                                ->addOptionVote($optionId, $product->getId());
                    }

                    $review->aggregate();
                    $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('You submitted your review for moderation.'));
                } catch (\Exception $e) {
                    $this->reviewSession->setFormData($data);
                    $this->messageManager->addError(__('We can\'t post your review right now.'));
                }
            } else {
                $this->reviewSession->setFormData($data);
                if (is_array($validate)) {
                    foreach ($validate as $errorMessage) {
                        $this->messageManager->addError($errorMessage);
                    }
                } else {
                    $this->messageManager->addError(__('We can\'t post your review right now.'));
                }
            }
        }
        $redirectUrl = $this->reviewSession->getRedirectUrl(true);
        $resultRedirect->setUrl($redirectUrl ?: $this->_redirect->getRedirectUrl());
        return $resultRedirect;
    }

}
```

Comment: Please have a look in to the below post.  It will help you to understand how this can be done,  https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/158541/magento-2-how-to-send-data-using-ajax-form-in-custom-form

Comment: Thanks you, But in my scenario, the result is redirected, that causes issue, and here it is a overrided controller

Comment: Hi @Jaisa could you please update the full code, I want to show the review form in popup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please remove the alert function `alert(reviewurl);` from your js file and modify you controller file as follows and try,

```
namespace XXX\YYY\Controller\Index;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
class Index extends \Magento\Review\Controller\Product\Post
{
  public function execute()
  {
    $message = null;
    $status = null;  
    if (!$this->formKeyValidator->validate($this->getRequest())) {
        $message[] = "Invalid form key";
        $status = 'failed';
    }
    else 
    {
         $data = $this->reviewSession->getFormData(true);

         if ($data) {
            $rating = [];
            if (isset($data['ratings']) && is_array($data['ratings'])) {
                $rating = $data['ratings'];
            }
        } else {
            $data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
            $rating = $this->getRequest()->getParam('ratings', []);
        }

        if (($product = $this->initProduct()) && !empty($data)) 
        {
            /** @var \Magento\Review\Model\Review $review */
            $review = $this->reviewFactory->create()->setData($data);
            $review->unsetData('review_id');

            $validate = $review->validate();
            if ($validate === true) {
                try {
                    $review->setEntityId($review->getEntityIdByCode(Review::ENTITY_PRODUCT_CODE))
                            ->setEntityPkValue($product->getId())
                            ->setStatusId(Review::STATUS_PENDING)
                            ->setCustomerId($this->customerSession->getCustomerId())
                            ->setStoreId($this->storeManager->getStore()->getId())
                            ->setStores([$this->storeManager->getStore()->getId()])
                            ->save();

                    foreach ($rating as $ratingId => $optionId) {
                        $this->ratingFactory->create()
                                ->setRatingId($ratingId)
                                ->setReviewId($review->getId())
                                ->setCustomerId($this->customerSession->getCustomerId())
                                ->addOptionVote($optionId, $product->getId());
                    }

                    $review->aggregate();
                    $message[] = __('You submitted your review for moderation.');
                    $status = 'success';
                } catch (\Exception $e) {
                    $this->reviewSession->setFormData($data);
                    $message[] = __('We can\'t post your review right now.');
                    $status = 'failed';
                }
            } else {
                $this->reviewSession->setFormData($data);
                if (is_array($validate)) {
                    foreach ($validate as $errorMessage) {
                        $message[] = $errorMessage;
                    }
                } else {
                    $message[] = __('We can\'t post your review right now.');
                }
                $status = 'failed';
            }
        }
    }

    $result = $this->resultFactory
->create(\Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON)
->setData([
    'messages' => $message,
    'status' => $status,
]);

 return $result;
  }
}
```

Comment: And it also shows resultfactory is unused statement

Comment: It shows also 503 error

Comment: check the error log and see whats the error. Also try to inject the result factory

Comment: In error log in shows  {"0":"Notice: Undefined variable: message

Comment: I have updated the answer. Now make sure your form data is available in the controller and the data is saved. Try to log the activity in your controller. It will help you to debug

Comment: It is also shows status as undefined

Comment: And the form data is not saved

Comment: And shows 503 error

Comment: It returns response as null for both message and status

Comment: now whats the error in the log ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70494/discussion-between-sri-and-mgento).