# Invalid Return Type in Ajax Call

Tags: magento2, javascript, ajax

I made an ajax script to (at the moment) simply return some HTML to a select.

My function looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
    showLoader: true,
    data: {val: inputVal},
    /*dataType: 'json', (un)commenting this doesn't change anything*/
    url: '/garage/data/get',
    type: 'post',
    success: function(res) {console.log(res)},
    error: function(res) {console.log(res)}
})
```

My Data/Get.php controller file:

```
<?php
    namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Data;

    use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;

    class Get extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
    {
       protected $resultJsonFactory;

        public function __construct(
            Context $context,
            \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory
        )
        {
            $this->resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory;
            parent::__construct($context);
        }

        public function execute()
        {
            $result = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();

            if ($this->getRequest()->isAjax()) {
               return '<option>treyBake was here</option>';
            }
        }
    }
```

Triggering the AJAX call returns this in console:

> Error log record number: 1086239430194

Going to that log shows:

> {"0":"Invalid return type","1":"#0 /var/www/magento2-site/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(256): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()\n#1 /var/www/unity/pub/index.php(41): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))\n#2 {main}","url":"/garage/data/get","script_name":"/index.php"}

The main error from that mess:

> Invalid return type

How do I go about debugging/resolving this error?

**Edit:** code I've tried:

> Data/Get.php

```
<?php
    namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Data;

    class Get extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
    {
        protected $resultJsonFactory;
        protected $resultFactory;

        public function __construct(
            \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
            \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory,
            \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory $resultFactory
        )
        {
            $this->resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory;
            $this->resultFactory = $resultFactory;

            parent::__construct($context);
        }

        public function execute()
        {
            $result = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();
            $response = '200';

            $resultJson = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON);
            $resultJson->setData($response);

            return $resultJson;
        }
    }
```

With my js in my .phtml template file as:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(['jquery', 'module'], function($, script)
    {
        //<![CDATA[
        jQuery(document).ready(function($)
        {
            $('select.filter-select').change(function()
            {
                let ajaxReq,
                    value = $(this).val();

                ajaxReq = $.ajax({
                    url: '<?php echo $block->getUrl("module/data/get"); ?>',
                    type: 'post',
                    showLoader: true,
                    data: {val: value}
                });

                ajaxReq.done(function(res, txtStatus, jqXHR)
                {
                    console.log(res);
                });

                ajaxReq.fail(function(XMLHttpRequest, txtStatus, err)
                {
                    console.log(XMLHttpRequest);
                    console.log(txtStatus);
                    console.log(err);
                });
            });
        });
        //]]>
    });
</script>
```

This returns:

> ## There has been an error processing your request
>
> *Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.*
>
> Error log record number: 616547725800

Going to var/report/616547725800 shows:

> {"0":"Source class \"\Vendor\Module\Controller\Data\Result\" for \"Vendor\Module\Controller\Data\ResultFactory\" generation does not exist."

This happens both **before** and **after** the below commands:

```
$ php bin/magento setup:upgrade
$ php bin/magento setup:di:compile
$ php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
$ php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Comment: don't use controllers for receiving API requests. use the webapi

Comment: @PhilippSander this is the recommended way on their documentation?

Comment: please provide the link

Comment: @PhilippSander ah my bad - not M2 docs. but SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38220376/how-i-get-ajax-response-from-controller-in-magento-2 && https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/158541/magento-2-how-to-send-data-using-ajax-form-in-custom-form

Comment: use the webapi... it's cleaner. you might also notice that you can't just return a html string

Comment: @PhilippSander no - you have to echo (just like any vanilla AJAX script) - managed to fix my issue but I'll look into webapis later .. any links / etc.?

Comment: echo? ewwww :D https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/get-started/bk-get-started-api.html

Comment: @PhilippSander see updated question :)

Answer (score 0):

If you really just want to send data from PHP controller to javascript, you can archive it by changing `JsonFactory` to `RawFactory`. Of course, you have to return instance of object which factory creates with filled data. Your code should look like this :

```
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;

class Get extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
   protected $resultRawFactory;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RawFactory $resultRawFactory
    ) {
        $this->resultRawFactory = $resultRawFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $result = $this->resultRawFactory->create();

        if ($this->getRequest()->isAjax()) {
           return $result->setContents('<option>treyBake was here</option>');
        }
    }
}
```

... however this is not good practice *( not Magento nor Web )*. For better solution I would return `JsonFactory` instance with set data *( array )*, but you have to parse them on javascript side also. The best solution would be to use webapi as @philip-sander suggested. *( but this topic is far more bigger )*

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    jQuery("#login-form").submit(function(event) { // On submit form.
        var ajaxRequest;
        event.preventDefault();
        var values = jQuery(this).serialize(); //serialize form data.
        var url=jQuery(this).attr("action");

            ajaxRequest = jQuery.ajax({
                url: "<?php echo $block->getUrl('frontname/controllerfolder/controllername'); ?>",
                type: "POST",
                beforeSend: function () {
                    jQuery('#loader').show();
                },
                data: values
            });

            ajaxRequest.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                // show successfully for submit message
                jQuery("#ajaxResponse").html(response);
                jQuery('#loader').hide();
                if(response == '200'){
                    jQuery("#ajaxResponse").html('Good !');
                }
            });

            /* On failure of request this function will be called  */
            ajaxRequest.fail(function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {

                console.log('error textStatus', textStatus);
                console.log('error errorThrown', errorThrown);

                // show error
                jQuery("#ajaxResponse").html('Oups, Error');
                jQuery('#loader').hide();
            });
    });
    //]]>
</script>
```

Controller :

```
<?php
    namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Data;

    use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;

    class Get extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
    {
       protected $resultJsonFactory;
       protected $resultFactory;    

        public function __construct(
            \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context, //updated
            \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory,
            \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory
        )
        {
            $this->resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory;
            $this->resultFactory = $resultFactory;
            parent::__construct($context);
        }

        public function execute()
        {
            $result = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();
            $response ='200';
            $resultJson = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON);
            $resultJson->setData($response);
            return $resultJson;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ok so after all changes I get `internal server error` in the console - I did add `ini_set` to the top of the class to see if it would return any errors but nada - any way to debug?

Comment: Ok managed to get the error returned:  `Source class \"\\Vendor\\Module\\Controller\\Data\\Result\" for \"Vendor\\Module\\Controller\\Data\\ResultFactory\" generation does not exist`

Comment: try : `php bin/magento setup:di:compile`

Comment: Already tried^^

Comment: Remove the content `var/generation` or `generated` then compile again.

Comment: same error still :/

Comment: solution: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/255238/generation-does-not-exist

Comment: This is not working. Tried all steps.

Comment: Add this line into your ajax code  : dataType: 'JSON',