# Generation does not exist

Tags: magento2, ajax

I have this code for a AJAX call:

> Controller/Data/Get.php

```
<?php
    namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Data;

    class Get extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
    {
        protected $resultJsonFactory;
        protected $resultFactory;

        public function __construct(
            \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
            \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory,
            \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory $resultFactory
        )
        {
            $this->resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory;
            $this->resultFactory = $resultFactory;

            parent::__construct($context);
        }

        public function execute()
        {
            $result = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();
            $response = '200';

            $resultJson = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON);
            $resultJson->setData($response);

            return $resultJson;
        }
    }
```

With my js in my .phtml template file as:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(['jquery', 'module'], function($, script)
    {
        //<![CDATA[
        jQuery(document).ready(function($)
        {
            $('select.filter-select').change(function()
            {
                let ajaxReq,
                    value = $(this).val();

                ajaxReq = $.ajax({
                    url: '<?php echo $block->getUrl("module/data/get"); ?>',
                    type: 'post',
                    showLoader: true,
                    data: {val: value}
                });

                ajaxReq.done(function(res, txtStatus, jqXHR)
                {
                    console.log(res);
                });

                ajaxReq.fail(function(XMLHttpRequest, txtStatus, err)
                {
                    console.log(XMLHttpRequest);
                    console.log(txtStatus);
                    console.log(err);
                });
            });
        });
        //]]>
    });
</script>
```

This returns:

> ## There has been an error processing your request
>
> *Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.*
>
> Error log record number: 616547725800

Going to var/report/616547725800 shows:

> {"0":"Source class \"\Vendor\Module\Controller\Data\Result\" for \"Vendor\Module\Controller\Data\ResultFactory\" generation does not exist."

This happens both **before** and **after** the below commands:

```
$ php bin/magento setup:upgrade
$ php bin/magento setup:di:compile
$ php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
$ php bin/magento cache:flush
```

What's wrong with my code? :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change **$resultJson = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON);** this line.

Use following line:

```
$resultJson = $this->resultFactory->create(\Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON);
```