# AJAX call to admin controller not working error code 302 found magento 2

Tags: magento2, ajax

here is my code response is 302 no found but when i check this controller directly by url it is working fine

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            var customurl = "<?php echo $baseUrl.'admin/pricingoption/option/editfieldphtml'?>";
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: customurl,
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: { },
            complete: function(response) {    
                // console.log(response);    
                console.log('bxhgjkhgfdsfghjkhgfd');   
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, errorThrown) {
                    console.log('Error happens. Try again.');
                }
            });
        });
```

ADDITIONAL INFO:
I am getting this error because of POST call i dont know why it is behaving like such on admin side so i have to change my ajax call to GET and it works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am getting this error because of POST call i dont know why it is behaving like such on admin side so i have to change my ajax call to GET and it works fine

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/177580)

Comment: thanks bro its done

Answer (score 0):

Add echo , exit in controller execute method.
Check the ajax request is getting called or not in network in chrome browser.
If its called , right click and visit the url in another tab , check if echo exit is their or not.

Comment: already checked ajax call through 302 not found and URL shows data

Comment: read the question already told these checks

Comment: Try in different browser. Or refer here for code reference -https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/158541/magento-2-how-to-send-data-using-ajax-form-in-custom-form

Comment: already checked that answer let me change the browser

Comment: Also take a look at the log files , if there is any error.