# How to get magento wishlist product list block on my custom phtml file?

Tags: magento2.4.1, magento-2-commerce

I want to get my wishlist product list block actually available in wishlist landing page,

[image]

How to get this wishlist block in my custom phtml file?

Answer (score 0):

You can try for this [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/332453/magento-2-how-to-get-data-from-input-fields-with-modal-widget-button/332456)

Or

also try for [this](https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/get-wishlist-collection-of-customer-by-customer-id-magento-2/)

Comment: I created module using this https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/get-wishlist-collection-of-customer-by-customer-id-magento-2/ how to get the block into my  phtml file

Comment: <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template")->setTemplate("My_Vendor::wishlistitems.phtml")->toHtml(); ?>

Comment: The responce not return

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/121364/magento-2-how-to-call-any-block-function-in-phtml   Check this link . I hope it helps you.