# How can I retrieve data from database when I change the drop down?

Tags: magento2

I have created a custome module for window calculation there is a drop down that we can select color in my .phtml file like below

```
<p><br>Frame Color</p>
<select id="color">
<option value="White">White</option>
<option value="Red">Red</option>
<option value="Green">Green</option>
<option value="Black">Black</option>
<option value="Wood limitation">Wood limitation</option>
</select>

<b><p id="framecolor"></p></b>
```

if i select something from my drop down it will change the value. I have used jQuery foe that like below in my .js file

```
//frame color calculation
        var color = jQuery('#color').val();

        if(color=="White"){
            var framecolor = (0);
        }
        else if(color=="Red"){
            var framecolor = (4);
        }
        else if(color=="Green"){
            var framecolor = (8);
        }
        else if(color=="Black"){
            var framecolor = (12);
        }
        else if(color=="Wood limitation"){
            var framecolor = (18);
        }
        jQuery("#framecolor").html("FrameColor Price: " + framecolor);
```

Now Im using hard coding for display price. Its not the good way so I created a database table like below

```
id      color     price_component
1       white     0
2       red       4
3       green     8
4       black     12
```

How can I get values from databse table when I select something from the drop down. Can someone tell me how to that step by step

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by AJAX. Please refer [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/128669/how-to-make-a-simple-ajax-call-in-magento-2-1-0#answer-128670) answer to add AJAX in your module.
You can send Frame color as `Ajax.data` to your controller where you could get its value from the table and show back in your phtml.

**Note:** This would be your controller action path.

`"AjaxUrl": "<?php echo $block->getAjaxUrl(); ?>"`